# How do I make this warning go away when using styled-components? - className prop is not being passed down to a child

Tags: styled-components

I have a `styled-component` and when it is rendered on the page I get a warning that I would like to understand how to fix.  Here is my component:

```
const TitleBar = styled.nav`
    background-color: #2f323b;
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
`;

const Link = styled.a`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    margin-left: 15px;
`;

export default () => 
    <TitleBar>
        <Link>
            <Wrapper>
                <BrandInverse />
            </Wrapper>
        </Link>
    </TitleBar>
```

This the only place in the app that I use the `nav` element.  Here is the warning I get:

`It looks like you've wrapped styled() around your React component (nav), but the className prop is not being passed down to a child. No styles will be rendered unless className is composed within your React component.`

Why is this happening?  How do I fix this?  What is the proper way to do this in the future?